# How to get latest object of array from users in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

> my mongodb structure

```
//First user
    _id:ObjectId("12345")
    name:"prudhvi"
    authors:Array
    0:Object
    authorId:"77777"
    authortitle:"medicine"
    1:Object
    authorId:"66666"
    authortitle:"Hospital"

//second user
    _id:ObjectId("67890")
    name:"venkat"
    authors:Array
    0:Object
    authorId:"55555"
    authortitle:"Doctor"
    1:Object
    authorId:"44444"
    authortitle:"Nurse"
```

Can someone please help here i have two users, On that i need to get only the latest object of authors array. Here my latest Object is 1:Object, If in case one more is added, I need to get 2:Object of data of all users.

> I tried like this but i am getting all objects of authors array, But i need to get latest object

```
userRouter.post('/getAuthors', function (req, res) {
Collections.user.find(req.body.user, function (err, result) {
if (err) res.status(500).send("There was a problem finding the user");
if (result.length > 0) {
res.status(200).send(result[0].authors);
}
}).select({ "authors": 1 });
});
```

Comment: You need a `createdAt` timestamp that you can use to sort the documents. MongoDB does not offer a `getLatest` functionality.

Comment: Mongodb generates the ObjectIds using timestamp and some random number. So the natural ordering is enough for your requirement. Have a look at the answer provided by Nimish Gupta below.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
Collections.user.find().limit(1).sort({$natural:-1})
```

Take a look at [$natural](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/meta/natural/) and [cursor.sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/)

Answer (score 0):

In your mongoose schema you can set timestamps. it will automatically set `createdAt` time stamp when you create a object from that schema and if you edit that particular object it set `updatedAt` timestamp.

As a example schema,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const markSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    mark: { type: Number },
    student: { type: String }, 
    },{
        timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Mark', markSchema);
```

like this you can set timestamps.